# Duplicate Product URL Key

Tags: magento-1.9, product, url-rewrite

I have products using the same URL Keys and I need a way to remove all of the URL Keys, so Magento regenerate them all according to their names.

Comment: @Zerocard Is it happening for all of the products?

Comment: i've tried several solutions, but none of them worked for me

http://www.atwix.com/magento/duplicated-product-url-keys-in-community-edition/

https://gist.github.com/fbrnc/5464097

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following query to see which products have duplicate URL keys and how many duplicates there are:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT entity_id) AS amount, `value`, entity_id
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar v
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM eav_attribute a
  WHERE attribute_code = "url_key"
  AND v.attribute_id = a.attribute_id
  AND EXISTS (
     SELECT *
     FROM eav_entity_type e
     WHERE entity_type_code = "catalog_product"
     AND a.entity_type_id = e.entity_type_id
  )
)
GROUP BY v.VALUE
ORDER BY `amount` DESC;
```

There is also a bug in the URL indexer that appends very large numbers to the end of URL's if duplicates exist, so you might want to look into that.

More information: https://erfanimani.com/issues-with-magentos-catalog-url-rewrite-indexer/

Answer (score 1):

In Order to  remove **exiting products urls from system**.You need to follow below steps:

1. First Take backup of **core_url_rewrite** table.
2. Then you need to running  some mysql delete queries at **core_url_rewrite**
   which will delete.

**Sql1:**

> Delete FROM core_url_rewrite WHERE product_id is not null

**Sql2:**

> Delete FROM core_url_rewrite WHERE category_id is  not null

3.delete All exiting url_keys from catalog_product_entity_varchar table.

> DELETe FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id
>   =(SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code LIKE 'url_key' and entity_type_id=4 )

4. Then re-index  **Catalog URL Rewrites**  from **Index Management**

Comment: i've removed the core_url_rewrite already,, but the thing is step 3 didn't work because somehow the entity_type might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:

1. In case things go wrong, make a backup of `core_url_rewrite` table and data
2. In app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php line 809 change

   ```
   if ($product->getUrlKey() == '' && !empty($requestPath)
       && strpos($existingRequestPath, $requestPath) === 0
   )
   ```

   to

   ```
   if (!empty($requestPath)
       && strpos($existingRequestPath, $requestPath) === 0
   )
   ```
3. Truncate (empty) the `core_url_rewrite` table
4. Under *System -> Index Management* re-index the Catalog URL Rewrites data

You should now be able to re-index again without creating thousands of random URL rewrites.